# Hi, I am editing a ros wiki page for my package. I wish to add mathematical equations in that but unable to do so

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried using the markdown language tool as discusses http://csrgxtu.github.io/2015/03/20/Writing-Mathematic-Fomulars-in-Markdown/, but failed :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299127/hi,-i-am-editing-a-ros-wiki-page-for-my-package.-i-wish-to-add-mathematical-equations-in-that-but-unable-to-do-so./) by [Sakshi19K](https://answers.ros.org/users/36753/sakshi19k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS wiki uses [MoinMoin](https://moinmo.in), not Markdown, so the page you link to isn't relevant.

You can check [wiki/HelpOnEditing](http://wiki.ros.org/HelpOnEditing) and [wiki/HelpOnMoinWikiSyntax](http://wiki.ros.org/HelpOnMoinWikiSyntax) to see what is supported.

Beyond that, I'm afraid you're going to have to resort to 'tricks' (ie: including images with your equations rendered (by something else) or embedding an html snippet that uses some service to render the equations).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sakshi19K](https://answers.ros.org/users/36753/sakshi19k/) on 2018-08-01**:
okay! thanks for the information.